# Charm-crypto how to do elementwise exponentiation in matrix?

Tags: python, cryptography, charm-crypto

I am working on a project for cryptography course working with Charm jhuisi [link](https://jhuisi.github.io/charm/cryptographers.html) .
I have two numpy matrix: V(2,3) belonging to ZR and M(3x2) belonging to G1. I want to bring V to G1, so I can exponentiate M^V. To perform this operation, in Charm I cannot simply use M**V, but I have to do it element by element.

```
from charm.toolbox.pairinggroup import PairingGroup,ZR,G1,G2,GT,pair
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[group.random(G1) for i in range(2)] for j in range(3)])

V_t = np.transpose(np.array([[group.random(ZR) for i in range(2)] for j in range(3)]))

matrix = np.array([[M[i][j] ** V[j][i] for j in range(3)] for i in range(2)]
```

but it returns me an error `"IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2"`

Can someone who has used Charm before help me, please?

Comment: What's the point of transposing a random array?

Comment: You can't create list elements by assigning to an index. Use `append()`.

Comment: You use `numpy`, but `z` is not a `numpy` matrix. It is an empty list, so if you do `z[i]` you get an IndexError.

Comment: You can also use nested list comprehensions.

Comment: To be clear: you have two Numpy arrays, and you want the result of matrix multiplication of those two arrays? That is *built-in*: the code is simply `M @ V`.

Comment: @Karl I just tried to simplify, I'm using Charm-crypto and the random functions create element belonging to Pair Group G1. So I cannot use M@V, I have to use the operator ** which is typical and full of meaning for the pairing.

@Barmar how can I use list comprehensions? I tried with `matrix = [[M[i][j] ** V_t[j][i] for j in range(3)] for i in range(2)]`  but it returns me Index error.

Comment: Are you looking for `M ** V.T`? Just transpose the exponents back to match the shape of the first matrix and you can do the operation elementwise (which is the default for most operators). In general, iterating over numpy arrays (or indexes into them) is going to be the wrong approach. Use broadcasting instead!

Comment: Pardon; I skimmed over the code and missed the algorithm you had in mind, because I was misled by the array shapes. I can't understand the intended purpose, though, of looping over `k` in your code. But yes, `M ** V.T` sounds like what you are describing.

Comment: `matrix  = M**V_t` returns:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,2) (2,3)
I think this is because Charm can't perform ** operation in array, but needs elementwise. Can you describe me some example of broadcasting, please?

Comment: So I suspect the direct exponentiation won't actually do what you want because of the extra `k` loop you're showing. But your complaint that it doesn't work at all (rather than giving the wrong results) because of "Charm-Crypto" whatever that is, suggests that you're doing something fundamentally different than what you're showing in your example code. Please be more clear what you're actually doing. Is `np` not the numpy library we'd expect? Are you not running a regular Python interpreter?

Comment: @Blckknght take a look here [link](https://jhuisi.github.io/charm/cryptographers.html) to have a brief understanding of what Charm is and how group.random method works. It works on cyclic group for pairing, so group.random(G1) generates a tuple (x1,x2) of very big prime number belonging to this cyclic group G1.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't your indices just the wrong way around?

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import random

M = np.array([[random() for i in range(2)] for j in range(3)])
V = np.transpose(np.array([[random() for i in range(2)] for j in range(3)]))

matrix = [[M[i][j] ** V[j][i] for j in range(2)] for i in range(3)]
```

#### Edit

Here's a wild idea. Try:

```py
import numpy as np
from god_knows_what import random

M = np.array([[random() for i in range(2)] for j in range(3)], dtype=object)
V = np.transpose(np.array([[random() for i in range(2)] for j in range(3)], dtype=object))

matrix = np.array([[M[i][j] ** V[j][i] for j in range(2)] for i in range(3)], dtype=object)
```

If the last line fails, try

```py
matrix = np.array([[M[i][j] ** V[j][i] for j in range(3)] for i in range(2)], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Your code returns: IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

Comment: It does not? Have you tried it out?

Comment: Yes, I tried and re tried, but it returns the same error

Comment: You must have something else going on in your program then. I've written it completely self-contained now. Try just copying into a clean file. It works in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Yes, in normal python it works, but as I said, I'm working with Charm-crypto and pairing group. My "random" function is a group.random(G1) method, which creates a random tuple (x1,x2) belonging to group G1 which is paired with G2 and they are cyclic group.

Comment: So all the confusion boils down to you not telling us what type your mystery `random()` function returns... You write "values", so I assumed something scalar-ish like `float` or `int`.

Comment: Agree with you, I am really sorry, I only tried to simplify the discussion around bilinear group, cyclicity, pairing and lots of other cryptographic matters

Comment: If you write a complete, self-contained example (i.e. implement/`import` `random()`), we can take a crack at the actual problem, even without knowing the math.

Comment: @NewAtech See my edit. It might just work!

Comment: it does not work, it gives me same index error, I don't know why. I updated the original post, with some new info

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a confused mix of python lists and numpy arrays.  Lets first do the calculation with lists, and paying particular attention to keeping indices right.

Make 2 lists:

```
In [358]: M = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
In [359]: V = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Starting with an empty list, fill it with a new list:

```
In [360]: res = []
In [361]: for i in range(2):
     ...:     res1 = []
     ...:     for j in range(3):
     ...:         res1.append(M[i][j]**V[j][i])
     ...:     res.append(res1)
     ...: 
In [362]: res
Out[362]: [[1, 8, 243], [16, 625, 46656]]
```

Note how `i` range is 2, `j` range is 3, matching the lengths of the lists.

The same calculation using numpy arrays:

```
In [363]: np.array(M)**np.array(V).T
Out[363]: 
array([[    1,     8,   243],
       [   16,   625, 46656]])
```

`np.array(M)` is (2,3) shape; `np.array(V)` is (3,2).  To perform the elementwise power, `V` has to be transposed to (2,3).

The nested loop can be written as a comprehension - again with the same care over indices:

```
In [364]: [[M[i][j]**V[j][i] for j in range(3)] for i in range(2)]
Out[364]: [[1, 8, 243], [16, 625, 46656]]
```

## V_t

What is `V_t`?  I see

```
In [365]: from random import random
In [366]: V = np.transpose(np.array([[random() for i in range(2)] for j in rang
     ...: e(3)]))
In [367]: V
Out[367]: 
array([[0.8748556 , 0.10373381, 0.23399403],
       [0.95388354, 0.24060715, 0.38468676]])
In [368]: V.shape
Out[368]: (2, 3)
```

Have you done some undocumented transpose to produce a (3,2)?  If so then you need to use `V_t[i][j]`.  Are your problems just the result of a sloppy use of the transpose?

Comment: I tried to give you more info updating the original post. Take a look, please.